# Does the system of a spherical and massless mirror, at rest in our reference frame, with photons moving around in it, has a rest mass?

Tags: special-relativity, mass, mass-energy

Can we say that if a big number of photons is travelling in a perfect, massless spherical mirror which is at rest in our reference frame, the combined system of the massless mirror and the photons moving in it has a rest mass?

Comment: By saying the mirror is "massless", aren't you already defining it as having no rest mass?  It's mass is totally dependent on energy transferred to it by ricocheting photons, so how can it have rest mass?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about that too. I will make an edit to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Imagine that there  are only two photons, one with 4-momentum $(p,p,0,0)$ and the other with $(q,q cos(\theta),q sin(\theta),0)$, the sum of their 4-momentum will be $(p+q,p+q cos(\theta), q sin(\theta), 0)$, and because we take the mirror as massles (I will asume that it doesn't have a 4-momentum asociated with no one more thing than it's movement, like if it wass massive and we trow it's mass to zero), then the mirror+photons inside will have a rest mass $(p+q)^2-(p+q cos(\theta))^2-q^2 sin^2(\theta)=2pq(1-cos(\theta))$. A more detailed analysis will take into account the energy asociated with the potential that forbidds photons traveling outside it, probably.